# App crashing while trying to use AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to store a date with this: https://github.com/react-native-community/datetimepicker

The problem is that I want for the date to be saved in the AsyncStorage, possibly also to store several dates.

This is my code:

```
const onChange = async(event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
    setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
    setDate(currentDate);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('Date', selectedDate); // the problem is here, I believe
};
```

I'm not sure why this is crashing, I don't even get a chance to read the error since it crashes.

Comment: Did you import ``AsyncStorage`` from react-native?

Comment: Yes, I did import it

Comment: can you check the ``typeof`` of  ``selectedDate``?

Comment: It looks like AsyncStorage only supports strings not rich objects. You should stringify the value to store it.

Comment: How is it possible to stringify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `setItem` function expects a `string` not an `object`. You should stringify the date before calling the function. Here is an example with get/set:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem("my-key", JSON.stringify(date));

const date = await AsyncStorage.getItem("my-key");
console.log(new Date(date))
```

You can find more information in the [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/blob/master/docs/API.md#setitem).

Comment: Will accept this one! I console logged it and got this in return `"2020-12-21T23:15:30.000Z"` which is correct. Thanks!